# How read Epub in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, mobile, epub

So, I can parse epub files to html through epub-dart(https://pub.dev/packages/epub). But, there are some way to read epub in flutter more easily?

It's because I need to be able to select text, like Selectable Text widget, but if I just use flutter_html, I'm not able to select text.

Can someone help me? Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the customRender callback as documented [here](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_html#-example-tab-). It is a paramter of the `Html` constructor. Perhaps you can

```
      customRender: {
        "div": (RenderContext context, Widget child, attributes, _) {
          if(child is Text) {
            child = SelectableText(child.data);
          }
          return Container(child: child);
        },
      },
```

Unfortunately the customRender callback does not support patterns or anything so you would probably have to list all potential elements containing text like, li, h1,h2,div,span etc.

Comment: Thank you! I was looking for this!